# Loopback 4 extensions: how to use them with middleware sequence

Tags: middleware, loopback4

I would like to use packages like the following one with Loopback 4.:

https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-helmet#readme

There are several similar packages, they all have the same problem:

They still use the Action based sequence syntax, but Loopback comes with a Middleware based sequence now and the other syntax is deprecated.

I know I can add custom middleware to the sequence. But I don't see how should I use these Action based examples with the new syntax?

I mean, in Looback 4 middleware functions there is no dependency injection. However the helmet package makes use of that using the old syntax:

```
export class MySequence implements SequenceHandler {
  constructor(
    @inject(SequenceActions.FIND_ROUTE) protected findRoute: FindRoute,
    @inject(SequenceActions.PARSE_PARAMS) protected parseParams: ParseParams,
    @inject(SequenceActions.INVOKE_METHOD) protected invoke: InvokeMethod,
    @inject(SequenceActions.SEND) public send: Send,
    @inject(SequenceActions.REJECT) public reject: Reject,
    @inject(HelmetSecurityBindings.HELMET_SECURITY_ACTION)
    protected helmetAction: HelmetAction,
  ) {}

  async handle(context: RequestContext) {
    const requestTime = Date.now();
    try {
      const {request, response} = context;
      const route = this.findRoute(request);
      const args = await this.parseParams(request, route);

      // Helmet Action here
      await this.helmetAction(request, response);

      const result = await this.invoke(route, args);
      this.send(response, result);
    } catch (err) {
      ...
    } finally {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

So how do I wrap this.helmetAction(...) in a custom middleware, so I can add it to the sequence. I cannot inject like this in middleware, can I?

```
@inject(HelmetSecurityBindings.HELMET_SECURITY_ACTION)
protected helmetAction: HelmetAction,
```

The whole documentation on Middleware and Middleware sequence is confusing like hell, at least for me.

Any help please?

Comment: Looks like your question is answered in https://groups.google.com/g/loopbackjs/c/5GDjw3MhiW8/m/tgT6GVMAGAAJ?pli=1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the middleware in between other actions, you can use the `InvokeMiddleware` action, you can use this action multiple times in the sequence with different `EXTENSION_POINT`. You can read more about it [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Middleware.html#extend-sequence-with-more-than-one-middleware-actions).

Your sequence should look something like this -

```
...
@inject('middleware.postInvoke', {optional: true})
protected middlewarePostInvoke: InvokeMiddleware = () => {};
...

await this.invokeMiddleware(context);
const route = this.findRoute(request);
const args = await this.parseParams(request, route);
const result = await this.invoke(route, args);

// The second middleware chain for post-invocation processing
await this.middlewarePostInvoke(context);

....
```

And in the Application -

```
this.bind('middleware.postInvoke')
  .toProvider(InvokeMiddlewareProvider)
  .tag({[CoreTags.EXTENSION_POINT]: POST_INVOCATION_MIDDLEWARE});
this.sequence(SequenceWithMiddleware);

const helmetBinding = this.expressMiddleware(
  helmet,
  undefined, // configuration will be needed here as we bind it to the context
  {
    key: 'middleware.helmet',
    extensionPointName: POST_INVOCATION_MIDDLEWARE,
  },
)
  // Set the scope to be `TRANSIENT` so that the new config can be loaded
  .inScope(BindingScope.TRANSIENT);
```

For registering a middleware to be invoked by the invoke action, you need to use the `expressMiddleware` method as explained [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Express-middleware.html#register-express-middleware-to-be-executed-by-invokemiddleware-actions).